# parquet-tools from s3 cannot access file using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, parquet

I have a python script that create a `boto3` session with:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
```

Then I try to do:

```
parquet_meta = subprocess.check_output(f'parquet-tools inspect {file}', shell=True)
```

But this returns that cannot access s3 file or it does not exists.
I also tried to define an s3 client using the session:

```
service_resource = session.resource('s3')
```

But neither works.

There is a way to run that `parquet-tools` command from `s3` in the case I need to test it from local, and I need then a profile?

I know the code is okey because if I test the `parquet-tools` statement using a parquet file in my localhost it returns the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved.

You can use the param `--awsprofile`:

```
parquet_meta = subprocess.check_output(f'parquet-tools inspect {file} --awsprofile {mypofile}', shell=True)
```